# Нетипичный глагол в плане управления падежами

Tags: падежи, глаголы

Глагол **быть** в значении **являться** управляет творительным падежом в прошедшем и будущем времени:

> Он был человеком. Он будет человеком. Он был, есть и будет человеком.

Почему тогда он не принимает творительный падеж в настоящем времени?

> Он есть человеком.

Существуют ли ещё такие "чудные" глаголы, или это исключительный случай?

Answer (score 1):

Ср.: В некоторых провинциальных уездах Казанской губернии каждый четвёртый присяжный заседатель **был мусульманином**. [«Отечественные записки» (2003)]

Форма именительного падежа указывает на постоянный признак, творительный на временный. Так, в приведенном примере форма творительного падежа является двусмысленной: ее можно понять как постоянный признак, т.е. ‘каждый четвертый присяжный заседатель являлся мусульманином в течение всей своей жизни’ или как признак временный ‘каждому присяжному заседателю довелось хотя бы какое-то время быть мусульманином’. Хотя вторая трактовка маловероятна в силу внеязыковых причин, с грамматической точки зрения она вполне возможна. Употребление именительного падежа исключает эту двусмысленность.

Русская корпусная грамматика

Answer (score 0):

Есть и быть(находится/являться) - это совершенно разные слова.

Слова *есть* нет в современно английском. *Есть* - это то что существует(exist) без причины, но само причиной может являться. Поэтому *есть* не склоняется, и падежи не рождает, а все слова становятся именами, а не номинативами.

Он есть Человек - так, вероятно, понятнее, эталон человека. Он должен(в смысле волен, долг совпадает с его волей человека) поступать так. Он(есть) человек всегда.

Он является человеком - похож на человека по ряду признаков, но может является чем-то еще. Сейчас человек - а через несколько лет уже нет, раньше не был человеком.

В общем в западной философии много споров насчет экзистенциальных "состояний", только потому что там нет слова есть, а слово состояние невольно становится вперед экзистенции(существования), признаки(призраки) бегут вперед определяемого понятия, как телега едет вперёд лошади, и все понятия становятся временными состояниями - терминами, формальными номинативами, копией копии.

И я не уверен, что *есть* - это глагол.